# Are any Hindu scriptures in Pali?

Tags: scripture, language

Wikipedia article of [Pali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pali) says:

> Pali (Pāli) or Magadhan is a Prakrit language native to the Indian subcontinent. It is widely studied because it is the language of much of the earliest extant literature of Buddhism as collected in the Pāli Canon or Tipiṭaka and is the sacred language of some religious texts of Hinduism and all texts of Theravāda Buddhism."

Is this true? Are there any Hindu scriptures in Pali?